# Issue with displaying non-standard font in PsychoPy visual.TextStim

Tags: psychopy

I have installed an old font called SPSS Marker Set because it contains solid shapes. However, although it correctly displays the characters, only the top half of these is visible. I have tried all manner of changes but cannot get the whole characters to display.

Any help/advice gratefully received,

With thanks,

Philip.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, but just to make sure: do other fonts render correctly? Are you displaying one or several lines? Have you tried changing the font size? Are you using builder or Coder?

Comment: Platform? Font file type?

Comment: I have made some progress the problem seems to reside with pyglet the following code demonstrates the effectimport pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window()
label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world',
                          font_name='SPSS Marker Set',
                          font_size=36,
                          x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2,
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()

pyglet.app.run()

Comment: I have made some progress and the problem seems to reside with pyglet. The following code demonstrates the effect

import pyglet
window = pyglet.window.Window()
label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world',
                          font_name='SPSS Marker Set',
                          font_size=36,
                          x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2,
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()
pyglet.app.run()

The font is tff and installed with the other System Fonts.
Thanks 
Philip.